# How to use the splice and binary search on the data to delete and search

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search, splice

I am trying to the splice method but it is not working properly want to delete one user but it is deleting 2.

Also want to add the binary search button

this is the requirement for binary search

> Replace the sequential access algorithm to operate on the arrays with a binary search algorithm.
> To implement this, the array’s data must be sorted. You may refer to an online example available at `Array.prototype.sort()` to learn about sorting data in arrays.

```
 function Display_Athlete() {
        var text = "<hr/>";
        for (let i = 0; i < athlete_name.length; i++) {
            text += "Athlete No - " + (i + 1) + ",  Athlete Name is  " + athlete_name[i]
                + "   and height is " + athlete_height[i] + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = text;
    }

    //Created function to remove the user
    function Remove_Athlete() {
        var person = prompt("Enter the name to remove the Athlete");
        for (let i = 0; i < athlete_name.length; i++) {
            athlete_name.splice(person - 1, 1);
            athlete_height.splice(person - 1, 1);
            alert("  Athlete_name " + athlete_name + "   Athlete_height  " + athlete_height + "  is removed  ");
        }
    }

    //Create the function to find  the user 
    function Find_Athlete() {
        var person = prompt("Enter the name to Find the Athlete");
        var text = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < athlete_name.length; i++) {
            if (athlete_name[i] == person) {
                text += "Athlete No - " + (i + 1) + ",  Athlete Name is  " + athlete_name[i]
                    + "   and height is " + athlete_height[i] + "<br>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = text;
        if (text == "")
            alert(`${person} Invalid Athlete name`);
        return "";
    }

    function Binary_Search(){
        
    }
```

Comment: please see the image for some reason it does not let me add the code

Comment: can anyone help with the code